# I installed React- Native project Via create-react-native-app ,but file missing is called index.android.js?

Tags: react-native

[image]

Missed index.android.js file ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. From the above, it isn't obvious what you are asking, or what the problem is. Have a look at this first: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

In project created with `create-react-native-app` you don't get `index.android.js` / `index.ios.js` files. Infact you won't get those files even in projects created with `react-native-init` starting RN v0.49( https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.49.0 ). Maybe a typo in the question or some confusion `create-react-native-app` creates a React-Native app not an Native script app.

Comment: Yes , Its an typo error. i changed to native script to React native and i go through your solution. I will get back to you, if any further queries